# Changing the font family to 'Tahoma'

Tags: feature-request, arabic, fonts

I know it may be hard or not possible to achieve technically, but is it possible to set the font family to `Tahoma`, and make this font family apply to only Arabic letters? i.e, not affect Latin letters.

If not, is it acceptable to change the font family to `Tahoma` anyway even if it will affect Latin letters?

The difference is good enough to think about it, here are print-screens that show how more readable Arabic is read when written in Tahoma instead of `Helvetica Neue` (currently used), while Latin is not greatly affected. Not that I haven't increased the font size, the `Tahoma` font is bigger by default.

**"Helvetica Neue" Font (Currently used)**
[image: "Helvetica Neue" Font (Currently used)]

**"Tahoma" Font (Suggested)**
[image: "Tahoma" Font (Suggested)]

So what does the community (users) say? is it better?

And what does the SE management say? is it possible?

You can see the font used live [Here](http://wikitechie.net/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9).

Comment: Just for the sake of being pedantic: Are you sure the first shot is of Helvetica Neue, rather than the fallback Arial?

Comment: @goldPseudo: Should be, I should have the 'Helvetica Neue' font and so it will be applied, also I tried to remove Arial but nothing changed. If you think sth other you can edit and include a PrintScreen

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think the Tahoma Arabic font looks uglier and harder to read :( I think the problem can be solved with a bigger font size and other minor styling tweaks.

Comment: I agree with you that it's ugly as heck, but I *do* find it more readable in smaller sizes. So unless we're upping the font size for the whole site (making the English fonts uncomfortably large) I still think Tahoma, ugly as it is, is our best course.

Comment: @SystemDown Arabic text can be styled differently to have a larger font size.

Comment: Automatically? How can that be done? I thought CSS treated all languages equally when it comes to styling?

Comment: @SystemDown you would enclose the Arabic text in a separate div, either by automatically recognizing the Unicode codes or by having the user select Arabic mode or Arabic region or something like that (like the blockquote region).

Comment: That would require server side mojo. Can we actually do that? Change how the server side of things work?

Comment: @SystemDown I don't see why it should be a problem. Most "feature requests" will involve some server side work.

Comment: Then that would definitely be cool with me. UV

Comment: If they would accept supporting Arabic blocks, then we should ask them to make the text direction RTL too.